# fork = true example

Tags: apache, ant

I suppose the title is fairly self explanatory but I can't seem to find any examples on the 
fork(boolean) method in the Apache Ant API.

Is there anyway someone could either provide a fully functional simple example on how to create a second JVM that performs a task in another class or a link on how to properly implement it?

I found http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Java.html#setFork(boolean) but couldn't find anything.

Let me appologize in advance as my knowledge of it doesn't extend passed knowing that it is XML based (this will be my first experience with Ant).

Please feel free to ask for additional information if needed.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short example of building HelloWorld with Ant and then executing the Java task with the fork=true set in the XML.  Setting fork=true in the XML equates later to the api method you referenced.

```
<project name="StackOverflowAntFork" basedir="." default="all">

    <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>

    <target name="all" depends="compile, run"/>

    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="Compiles the source code" depends="prepare">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir};" destdir="${classes.dir}" debug="on" nowarn="on" deprecation="off" optimize="on" fork="true" memoryMaximumSize="256m" includeAntRuntime="false">
            <include name="**/HelloWorld.java"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.classes"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java classname="HelloWorld" dir="${classes.dir}" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="128m">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
                <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

</project>
```

If you are creating your own Ant task then this may not be what you were looking for.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! I think this will definitely put me in the right direction.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please 'accept' the answer.